# typeerror: column is not iterable join - Getting error while using with columns on multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm getting the same error with below code also but added paranthesis here
:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_final = df_retail_sales_transaction
.withColumn("eligible_8cpl_transaction_id", 
    when(df_retail_sales_transaction.transaction_key.isNull()
                                                 & (df_transaction_line_item.transaction_line_type == 'f')
                                                 & (df_transaction_payment.method_of_payment_code.isin(
    [1000136, 1000108, 1000127, 1000129, 1000115, 1000124, 1000109, 1000114]), 
    col("transaction_key")))
            .otherwise(lit(None)))
```

## Error

```
Getting error as follow :
[1000136, 1000108, 1000127, 1000129, 1000115, 1000124, 1000109, 1000114]), col("transaction_key")))
    raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the brackets wrong, it should be:

```
df_final = df_retail_sales_transaction.join(df_transaction_line_item, (df_retail_sales_transaction.transaction_id == df_transaction_line_item.transaction_id)
      & (df_retail_sales_transaction.transaction_key == df_transaction_line_item.transaction_key), 'inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a closing parenthesis , hence the Column not iterable error

**Note - Always fan out your brackets to ensure proper closures of parenthesis**

```
df_final = df_retail_sales_transaction.join(df_transaction_line_item
                    , (df_retail_sales_transaction['transaction_id'] == df_transaction_line_item['transaction_id'])
                    & (df_retail_sales_transaction['transaction_key'] == df_transaction_line_item['transaction_key'])
        , 'inner')
```

Comment: No, I think the parenthesis was set wrong. The last closing parenthesis is unnecessary.

Comment: The last bracket is the closing bracket for the for the one before eligible_8cpl_transaction_id:                         
              .withColumn("eligible_8cpl_transaction_id", 
    when(df_retail_sales_transaction.transaction_key.isNull()
                                                 & (df_transaction_line_item.transaction_line_type == 'f')
    & (df_transaction_payment.method_of_payment_code.isin(
    [1000136, 1000108, 1000127, 1000129, 1000115, 1000124, 1000109, 1000114]), 
    col("transaction_key")))
            .otherwise(lit(None)))